# FInd first non zero element in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am working with a pyspark dataframe and trying to see if there is a method that can extract me the index of first non zero element in spark dataframe. I have added the index column myself since pyspark does not support that, as opposed to pandas.

Comment: That'd be easier for us to answer if you add sample data and expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: when you say `first` you mean lowest ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

let's assume your dataframe looks like this :

```py
df.show()
+---+-----+                                                                     
|idx|value|
+---+-----+
|  0|    0|
|  1|    0|
|  2|    1|  # <-- We want this one
|  3|    2|
|  4|    3|
|  5|    4|
+---+-----+
```

you can achieve this easily with a `min`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.where(F.col("value") != 0).select(F.min("idx")).show()
```

or with a [`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df.where(F.col("value") != 0).withColumn(
    "rwnb", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("idx"))
).where(F.col("rwnb") == 1).select("idx").show()
+---+
|idx|
+---+
|  2|
+---+
```